# Returning a list of object from ajax to mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

i'll tell you my problem and then show you my code.
i want to send list of objects from ajax to mvc controller (JsonPermissions)
but i'm always getting null. all the other parameters are correct.
the data inside getpermissions(which you'll see later) are as the class from the mvc.
tried to vary things, but none of them seems to work

here's the ajax:

```
   $.ajax({
    url: '/Employees/ModifyEmployee',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        employee: new JsonEmployee(),
        contact: new JsonContact(),
        person: new JsonPerson(),
        permissions: new JsonPermissions(),
        password: new JsonPassword()
    }),
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.results.length) {                
            $('.wrapper').addClass('slideDown');
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
})
```

here's the JsonPermissions (function called getpermissions):

```
function GetPermissions()
{
     var values = $(".permission2employee input:checkbox:checked").map(function     () {
     row = $(this).closest("tr");

    return {
        EmployeePermissionsID: $(this).attr('id'),
        PermissionID: $(row).attr('id'),
        Description: $(row).find(".description").text(),
    }
}).get();

return values;
```

}

and here's the mvc code:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModifyEmployee(sp_GetEmployeeData_Result employee,
        sp_GetContact_Result contact,
        sp_GetPerson_Result person,
        List<sp_GetPermissions_Result> permissions,
        sp_GetPasswords_Result password)
    {
       // EmployeesModel.SetEmployeeData(employeeData);
        return Json(new { });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me,
I needed to send new jsonpermissions().Permissions
Not just jsonpermissions()